Find a sequence $x_n \to \infty$ such that $(e^{i\lambda_1 x_n }, \ldots , e^{i\lambda_N x_n }) \to (1,\ldots, 1)$
Let $\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_N \in \mathbb R$ be distinct. Let $\mathbb T \subset \mathbb C$ be the unit circle and $\mathbb T^n$ be the $n$-dimensional torus. This is a group under componentwise multiplication. Define the subgroup of the torus
$$G =   \{ (e^{i\lambda_1 x }, \ldots , e^{i\lambda_N x }) \in \mathbb T: x \in \mathbb R \}$$
and for each $r \ge 0$ define the sub-semigroup
$$S_r = \{ (e^{i\lambda_1 x }, \ldots , e^{i\lambda_N x }) \in \mathbb T: x \ge r \}.$$
I wonder is there an elementary proof that $\overline {S_r}$ contains the point $(1,\ldots, 1)$ which is the identity of the group.
The fact that this is true follows from a more general result proved here by Uri Bader. A closed semigroup of a compact topological group is in fact a group.
Since the group operations are continuous, it follows that the closure of a sub-semigroup is itself a sub-semigroup. In particular $\overline {S_r}$ is a closed sub-semigroup of the torus. Hence it is a group, and must contain the identity element. Hence $(1,\ldots, 1) \in \overline {S_r}$ as required.
While this method is powerful, it doesn't offer much insight into what is going on with the exponentials in this particular case.
Is it possible to prove the result by explicitly constructing a sequence $x_n \to \infty$ such that $\max_{j \le N}|e^{i \lambda_jx} -1| \to 0$.

This is immediate from the Dirichlet approximation theorem

It is a corollary of Dirichlet's approximation theorem that for every real numbers $a_1,\dots,a_N$, every positive integer $q$, and every positive real number $t_0$, there exists a real number $t\in[t_0,t_0q^N]$ such that $d(ta_j,\Bbb Z)\le1/q\quad(j=1,2, \ldots,N)$.
This statement is proved for instance (under the name Dirichlet's theorem) in E. C. Titchmarsh's Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function, Clarendon Press, 1951, chap. VIII, § 8.2, p. 184-185, using the pigeonhole principle.

A proof of the claim, though not an explicit construction of the requested sequence $x_n \to \infty.$
Let $\lambda_{j},j=1,2,3,\ldots,N$ be real numbers and let $r$ be
a real number. The claim is: Given any $\epsilon>0,$ is there
a real number $x,$ such that $x>r$ and $\left|e^{i2\pi\lambda_{j}x}-1\right|<\epsilon$
for $j=1,2,3,\ldots,N.$
Let
$$
f(x):=1+\sum_{j=1}^{N}e^{i2\pi\lambda_{j}x}.
$$
The proof is divided into three steps. Only Step 3 is non-trivial, so the reader is advised to skip the proofs of the first two steps on a first reading.
Step 1. For any $x,$ $0\leq\left|f(x)\right|\leq1+N.$
Step 2. If for some $x$ and some $0<\delta<1$ we have $\left|f(x)\right|\geq1+N-\delta,$
then for each $j,$ we have $\left|e^{i2\pi\lambda_{j}x}-1\right|<\sqrt{8\delta}.$
Step 3. $\limsup_{x\to\infty}\left|f(x)\right|=1+N.$
Combining Steps 2 and 3 completes the proof of the claim.
Proof of Step 1: This follows from the triangle inequality,
since $\left|e^{i2\pi\lambda_{j}x}\right|=1.$
Proof of Step 2: If we think of complex numbers as vectors
in the plane, then the sum of $1+N$ unit vectors can only have length
close to $1+N$ if the vector are all close to parallel, that is all
the $e^{i2\pi\lambda_{j}x}$ are close to parallel to $1.$ Hence
all the differences $e^{i2\pi\lambda_{j}x}-1$ are close to zero.
This explains the ``$1+$'' in the definition of $f(x).$
The following provides a quantitative version of this argument. Fix
$j.$ Using the triangle inequality as in Step 1 we have $1+N-\delta\leq\left|f(x)\right|\leq\left|1+e^{i2\pi\lambda_{j}x}\right|+N-1.$
Hence, $2-\delta\leq\left|1+e^{i2\pi\lambda_{j}x}\right|.$ Consequently,
$$
4-4\delta\leq(2-\delta)^{2}\leq\left|1+e^{i2\pi\lambda_{j}x}\right|^{2}=2+2\cos\left(2\pi\lambda_{j}x\right)
$$
so $1-2\delta\leq\cos\left(2\pi\lambda_{j}x\right),$ that is
$$
1-\cos\left(2\pi\lambda_{j}x\right)\leq2\delta.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sin^{2}\left(2\pi\lambda_{j}x\right)=\left(1+\cos\left(2\pi\lambda_{j}x\right)\right)\left(1-\cos\left(2\pi\lambda_{j}x\right)\right)\leq4\delta.
$$
Finally, combining the previous two inequalities we have
$$
\left|1-e^{i2\pi\lambda_{j}x}\right|^{2}=\left(1-\cos\left(2\pi\lambda_{j}x\right)\right)^{2}+\sin^{2}\left(2\pi\lambda_{j}x\right)\leq4\delta^{2}+4\delta<8\delta
$$
as required.
Proof of Step 3: The proof is by contradiction. Suppose $\limsup_{x\to\infty}\left|f(x)\right|\neq1+N.$
By Step 1, there are real numbers $R,M$ such that $\left|f(x)\right|\leq M<1+N$
for all $x\geq R.$
Set $\lambda_{0}:=0.$ For a integer $n\geq1,$
let $\mathbf{N}_{n}$ denote the set of $1+N$ tuples $\left(k_{0},k_{1},\ldots,k_{N}\right)$
of integers $\geq0$ such that $k_{0}+k_{1}+\cdots+k_{N}=n.$ By the
multinomial theorem
\begin{align*}
\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^{n} & =\sum_{\left(k_{0},k_{1},\ldots,k_{N}\right)\in\mathbf{N}_{n}}\frac{n!}{k_{0}!k_{1}!\cdots k_{N}!}e^{i2\pi\sum_{j=0}^{N}k_{j}\lambda_{j}x}.
\end{align*}
It is easy to see that $\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}e^{itx}dx=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }t=0\\
0 & \text{if }t\neq0
\end{cases}.$ Hence, for $\left(\ell_{0},\ell_{1},\ldots,\ell_{N}\right)\in\mathbf{N}_{n}$
we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{n!}{\ell_{0}!\ell_{1}!\cdots\ell_{N}!} & \leq\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
\left(k_{0},k_{1},\ldots,k_{N}\right)\in\mathbf{N}_{n}\\
\sum_{j=0}^{N}k_{j}\lambda_{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{N}\ell_{j}\lambda_{j}
\end{array}}\frac{n!}{k_{0}!k_{1}!\cdots k_{N}!}\\
 & =\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^{n}e^{-i2\pi\sum_{j=0}^{N}\ell_{j}\lambda_{j}x}dx.
\end{align*}
Consequently, $\left|f(x)\right|\leq M<1+N$ when $x\geq R$ gives
$$
\frac{n!}{\ell_{0}!\ell_{1}!\cdots\ell_{N}!}\leq\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}\left|f\left(x\right)\right|^{n}dx\leq\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}M^{n}dx=M^{n}.
$$
The second inequality used that the values of $f\left(x\right)$ when
$x<R$ are irrelevant, when taking the limit. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\left(1+N\right)^{n} & =\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
\left(k_{0},k_{1},\ldots,k_{N}\right)\in\mathbf{N}_{n}\end{array}}\frac{n!}{k_{0}!k_{1}!\cdots k_{N}!}\\
 & \leq\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
\left(k_{0},k_{1},\ldots,k_{N}\right)\in\mathbf{N}_{n}\end{array}}M^{n}\\
 & \leq\left(1+n\right)^{1+N}M^{n}.
\end{align*}
Setting $x=0$ in the expression for $\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^{n}$
gives the equality and since the number of terms in the sum is smaller
than $\left(1+n\right)^{1+N}$ the second inequality holds.
Taking the logarithm of $\left(1+N\right)^{n}\leq\left(1+n\right)^{1+N}M^{n}$
gives
$$
\log\left(1+N\right)\leq\left(1+N\right)\tfrac{\log\left(1+n\right)}{n}+\log\left(M\right).
$$
But as $n\to\infty$ this yields a contradiction, since $1+N>M$ and
$\tfrac{\log\left(1+n\right)}{n}\to0.$
